# How do I do htaccess redirects with empty query params?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect my shop's URL `https://example.com/shop/?mylogout=` to `https://myshop.com/shop/my-account/?mylogout=` (adding the missing `/my-account/` in the middle of the URL).

I tried this in the `.htaccess` file inside of the `/shop/` folder:

```
Redirect 301 /?mylogout= https://example.com/shop/my-account/?mylogout=
```

And this:

```
Redirect 301 /shop/?mylogout= https://example.com/shop/my-account/?mylogout=
```

And this in my main `.htaccess` at the root of `example.com`:

```
Redirect 301 /shop/?mylogout= https://example.com/shop/my-account/?mylogout=
```

None of these worked, I assumed because the empty query param is messing it up.
How can I make this work?

My HTACCESS in /shop/.htaccess is below, with my domain changed for mydomain.net:

```html
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mylogout= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-account/?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,NC,L]

#Domain: mydomain.net
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
      Header set Content-Disposition "Attachment"
      Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<Files composer.lock>
    # Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>

    # Apache 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</Files>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
</IfModule>
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: how about you add the .htaccess code here?

Comment: I second Popeye here, once you add your .htaccess code file in your question, will add my answer which I had already written.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches on the _path_ component of the URL only, the documentation clearly explains that. If you want to do stuff based on query string content, then you need to use mod_rewrite, a `RewriteCond` can check the corresponding server variable, and then a following RewriteRule can perform the redirect.

Comment: Thanks, I added the HTACCESS from inside /shop/.htaccess
Can you provide suggested fixes?

Comment: @Marcturis You should address the answer below, that you seem to have "part used" already in your `.htaccess` file. But for some reason you've removed the all important `/shop` elements from it (so it certainly won't work as written)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mylogout= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/my-account/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```